# OCR - Border Whitespaces trimming in document images

Tags: ocr, crop, trim

I have such similar documents which has whitespaces in the corners.I tried to implement this below code but it doesnt work on some of the forms which has some noise in the borders.

I tried this code but [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rk3S.jpg)it didnt work on some document images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMkls.jpg)
[Trim scanned images with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528816/trim-scanned-images-with-pil)

Any help is appreciated